# 404 Page not Displaying

Tags: 404-error

I have a theme and it has a file "404.php" inside it. As I read on the documentation of the 404 Page for wordpress this file is needed. We I miss spell the url on my site the 404 Page must display but it isn't. What could be the reason for it?

Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

If it is not going to your 404.php , then is it redirecting to index.php.

**a.** If it is redirecting to index.php, can you please update the permalink setting and update the .htaccess file with that.

**b.** If the situation still arises can you please try deactivating the plugins one by one and see if any of the plugin is causing the issue.

Most probably point **a.** will solve your problem.

Thanks

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have a Cloudflare on my site. All "Not Found" Page are being handled by the "Smart Error" Feature of the Cloudflare. But still webmaster think it is a "Not Found" URL. So I really need to set-up a 404 Page for the 404 Error. @AftabAlam